# Why doesnt client.connect accept a full adress

Tags: ssl, arduino, ssl-certificate, esp32

i am trying to write a piece of code in which the ESP32 connect securely to my api-server and post some sensor data. For this i use the WifiClientSecure library.

Through trial and error i have found out that `client.connect(www.myserver.com, 443);`  works.

But `client.connect(www.myserver.com/api, 443);` will throw an error.
I have searched the internet for a solution but can't manage to find one.

Full code:

```
#include <arduino.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

const char* ssid     = "filled out ssid";     // your network SSID 
const char* password = "filled out password"; // your network password

const char*  server = "www.server.com/api";  // Server URL

/* use 
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.howsmyssl.com:443 </dev/null 
to get this certificate */
const char* ca_cert = \ 
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
"MIIF3jCCA8agAwIBAgIQAf1tMPyjylGoG7xkDjUDLTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQwFADCB\n" \
"iDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCk5ldyBKZXJzZXkxFDASBgNVBAcTC0pl\n" \
"cnNleSBDaXR5MR4wHAYDVQQKExVUaGUgVVNFUlRSVVNUIE5ldHdvcmsxLjAsBgNV\n" \
"BAMTJVVTRVJUcnVzdCBSU0EgQ2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbiBBdXRob3JpdHkwHhcNMTAw\n" \
"MjAxMDAwMDAwWhcNMzgwMTE4MjM1OTU5WjCBiDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNV\n" \
"BAgTCk5ldyBKZXJzZXkxFDASBgNVBAcTC0plcnNleSBDaXR5MR4wHAYDVQQKExVU\n" \
"aGUgVVNFUlRSVVNUIE5ldHdvcmsxLjAsBgNVBAMTJVVTRVJUcnVzdCBSU0EgQ2Vy\n" \
"dGlmaWNhdGlvbiBBdXRob3JpdHkwggIiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4ICDwAwggIK\n" \
"AoICAQCAEmUXNg7D2wiz0KxXDXbtzSfTTK1Qg2HiqiBNCS1kCdzOiZ/MPans9s/B\n" \
"3PHTsdZ7NygRK0faOca8Ohm0X6a9fZ2jY0K2dvKpOyuR+OJv0OwWIJAJPuLodMkY\n" \
"tJHUYmTbf6MG8YgYapAiPLz+E/CHFHv25B+O1ORRxhFnRghRy4YUVD+8M/5+bJz/\n" \
"Fp0YvVGONaanZshyZ9shZrHUm3gDwFA66Mzw3LyeTP6vBZY1H1dat//O+T23LLb2\n" \
"VN3I5xI6Ta5MirdcmrS3ID3KfyI0rn47aGYBROcBTkZTmzNg95S+UzeQc0PzMsNT\n" \
"79uq/nROacdrjGCT3sTHDN/hMq7MkztReJVni+49Vv4M0GkPGw/zJSZrM233bkf6\n" \
"c0Plfg6lZrEpfDKEY1WJxA3Bk1QwGROs0303p+tdOmw1XNtB1xLaqUkL39iAigmT\n" \
"Yo61Zs8liM2EuLE/pDkP2QKe6xJMlXzzawWpXhaDzLhn4ugTncxbgtNMs+1b/97l\n" \
"c6wjOy0AvzVVdAlJ2ElYGn+SNuZRkg7zJn0cTRe8yexDJtC/QV9AqURE9JnnV4ee\n" \
"UB9XVKg+/XRjL7FQZQnmWEIuQxpMtPAlR1n6BB6T1CZGSlCBst6+eLf8ZxXhyVeE\n" \
"Hg9j1uliutZfVS7qXMYoCAQlObgOK6nyTJccBz8NUvXt7y+CDwIDAQABo0IwQDAd\n" \
"BgNVHQ4EFgQUU3m/WqorSs9UgOHYm8Cd8rIDZsswDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgEGMA8G\n" \
"A1UdEwEB/wQFMAMBAf8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEMBQADggIBAFzUfA3P9wF9QZllDHPF\n" \
"Up/L+M+ZBn8b2kMVn54CVVeWFPFSPCeHlCjtHzoBN6J2/FNQwISbxmtOuowhT6KO\n" \
"VWKR82kV2LyI48SqC/3vqOlLVSoGIG1VeCkZ7l8wXEskEVX/JJpuXior7gtNn3/3\n" \
"ATiUFJVDBwn7YKnuHKsSjKCaXqeYalltiz8I+8jRRa8YFWSQEg9zKC7F4iRO/Fjs\n" \
"8PRF/iKz6y+O0tlFYQXBl2+odnKPi4w2r78NBc5xjeambx9spnFixdjQg3IM8WcR\n" \
"iQycE0xyNN+81XHfqnHd4blsjDwSXWXavVcStkNr/+XeTWYRUc+ZruwXtuhxkYze\n" \
"Sf7dNXGiFSeUHM9h4ya7b6NnJSFd5t0dCy5oGzuCr+yDZ4XUmFF0sbmZgIn/f3gZ\n" \
"XHlKYC6SQK5MNyosycdiyA5d9zZbyuAlJQG03RoHnHcAP9Dc1ew91Pq7P8yF1m9/\n" \
"qS3fuQL39ZeatTXaw2ewh0qpKJ4jjv9cJ2vhsE/zB+4ALtRZh8tSQZXq9EfX7mRB\n" \
"VXyNWQKV3WKdwrnuWih0hKWbt5DHDAff9Yk2dDLWKMGwsAvgnEzDHNb842m1R0aB\n" \
"L6KCq9NjRHDEjf8tM7qtj3u1cIiuPhnPQCjY/MiQu12ZIvVS5ljFH4gxQ+6IHdfG\n" \
"jjxDah2nGN59PRbxYvnKkKj9\n" \
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n" ;


/* create an instance of WiFiClientSecure */
WiFiClientSecure client;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);

    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

    /* waiting for WiFi connect */
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.print(".");
        delay(100);
    }

    Serial.print("Connected to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);

    /* set SSL/TLS certificate */
    client.setCACert(ca_cert);

    Serial.println("Connect to server via port 443");
    if (!client.connect(server, 443)){
        Serial.println("Connection failed!");
    } else {
        Serial.println("Connected to server!");
        /* create HTTP request */
        
        Serial.print("Waiting for response ");
        while (!client.available()){
            delay(50); //
            Serial.print(".");
        }  
        /* if data is available then receive and print to Terminal */
        while (client.available()) {
            char c = client.read();
            Serial.write(c);
        }

        /* if the server disconnected, stop the client */
        if (!client.connected()) {
            Serial.println();
            Serial.println("Server disconnected");
            client.stop();
        }
  }
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: on TCP level there is no URL. the WiFiClient (TCP socket) connects to IP address and port. the `connect` which takes hostname first resolves the IP address then calls the  `connect` which takes an IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`www.server.com/api` is a partial URL. The complete URL will be `https://www.server.com/api`,
where:

- `https` - This part is called scheme or protocol. HTTPS implies a default TCP port 443 (http mean port 80 by default)
- `www.server.com` - The domain part, can be called also server address.
- `api`- This is a path on the server

`WiFiClient`, or `WiFiClientSecure`, is the TCP client, it doesn't know anything about URLs. TCP client recognizes just address, given in form of IP address (192.168.1.20) or FQDN (which is then translated into IP address).

It is easier to use [HTTPClient](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/HTTPClient/examples/BasicHttpsClient/BasicHttpsClient.ino) for requesting HTTP resources.

edit: FNDQ->FQDN

Comment: English is not my first language so i sometimes don't get everything right away. I did not know about the fact that wificlient is a tcp client.

but what i get from your comment is that the TCP clients don't accept paths only FQDN(what i think you meant)?

Comment: @SrikenGames `WiFiClient` is very confusingly named, it's really not obvious from the name what it is. TCP is a reliable streaming protocol that knows nothing about HTTP. HTTP uses TCP to transport data, but HTTP is where all the knowledge about paths is. 100% agree on using `HTTPClient` for web access.